# Is the undo functionality possible in QGIS while creating a line feature?

Tags: qgis

I have noticed that when creating a new line feature in QGIS, control+z does not seem to be possible. When you insert a vertice of this line in a slightly wrong place, you cannot undo your actions (remove vertice). Control+z is only possible after finishing the feature, and in that case the whole feature is removed, and not the last verticed added.

Anything that solves this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I discovered after simply trying pretty much all keys possible. Backspace or del button does what is needed. Unfortuantely this is not shown at all in the QGIS menu interface.

I will leave this answer so as to avoid frustration by future users.

Comment: @Kurt feels wrong :P